# How to prevent Firebase Firestore from unnecessary read operations in a Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, listener

So in my Firestore db, I have about 2000 documents that contain images (blob) with some tags to group them, order them and search them on local device. In my app, images are stored in a local SQLFlite db and user is able to see them offline, Firestore offline persistance is also enabled. When device network connection is on, firestore listener reads all my queries again because my app shows my images according to the tags that I use to classify images, even if there is no changes in my Firestore db. Main reason for this is the 30 minutes rule:

> "Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
>   example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
>   if you had issued a brand-new query"

So, when my local and firestore db's does not change, I will be charged for all the queries caused by the tags of my images in every 30 minutes in the worst case, which may cause about 10000 reads for a user at max.

When we talk about maximum, we underestimate the "minimum" scenario. If user opens my app 4 times a day, it may cause 1000 reads, which I think is also expensive.

I am considering about some solutions:
1- any way to disable a Flutter apps network connection with some code while opening the app? For example if there is a network connection at the time an app opens, in the next 24 hours the app won't be able to connect the internet whether or not phones network connection is turned on/off.
2- any alternatives?

I know that I am kind of mis-using Firestore, but my database will probably change once in a day, so why reading every query over and over again in every 30 minutes?
As an amateur developer, any idea is appreciated, thanks a lot.

EDİT:
3- how about using realtime database + cloud storage instead of using Firestore with blob encoded images? I don't know if realtime db has some passive ways of billing like 30 minutes rule in Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

> my database will probably change once in a day, so why reading every query over and over again in every 30 minutes?

Good question. So why don't you store the timestamp of then you last requested data in your application state, and then when the app restarts only request data that was created/modified since then?

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar issue as OP.
We have succesfully implemented your method but how would one know which documents are deleted if you're using this method?

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing this problem. Every time the snapshots are reconnected, you get charged reads. If you have 1000 documents in a collection and user opens and closes the app a few times a day, this soon adds up..

Found this explaining the proposed answer in more detail, but I'm trying to get my head around how to update the cache data with only the newly modified data..

https://link.medium.com/GB4bEvVgUdb