# How to prevent unnecessary Document read in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, offline

This question is similar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517937/how-to-prevent-firebase-firestore-from-unnecessary-read-operations-in-a-flutter), but since I don't have enough reputation I cannot reply to any answers. So I created a new question instead.

I'm new to Flutter and Firebase. Please bear with me..
I'm planning to move my app from another database to Firestore.

So I have a Collection of 3K documents which contains image information and latest update timestamp in each of them. 
The problem is each time the app starts (if its 30 minutes apart) it will read the whole 3K documents and it shows in my Firebase console. 
During my test, an average user will cause about 8K-10K new reads per day!! Even if I use pagination, it will repeatedly re-read the same data over and over again and it's still count as new read.. Thats insane.. 
But if I disabled my network, the app actually able to fetch from cache even after a day without re-connecting to Firestore.

The images are added around 4 a day so it doesn't make sense to read the whole 3K documents each load.

I saw some solution using local DB. But whats the point of using Firestore if I need another local DB right? I hope I don't need to do that..

So I had an idea but I got stuck somewhere.. which is to store the latest update in SharedPreferences and just fetch documents since the latest update stored in cache. But I got stuck here, I hope someone could help me:

1. How can we disable Firestore network in Flutter and only read from cache? How do I know it's from cache?
2. How do I update the data in cache? Because if I do:

Firestore.instance.collection('images').where('last_update', isGreaterThan: lastUpdateInCache).snapshots();

This will only display the snapshots after that latest update.. Should I concatenate the list with the old ones? But I don't want to concatenate the list because that will mean I need to make copies of the data and it's a huge memory usage.

Does Firestore has a a function I don't know about to solve this one?

Thank you.. I'm an amateur so any reply would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally after looking high and low, apparently there is no solution at the moment other than saving data persistently in local DB.
Because:

1. All document that has been read will be re-read after 30 minutes of inactivity.
2. Simulating offline and online is very troublesome.

So finally my solution is:

1. Use Sembast as the local DB (so far so good) to persist data.
2. Create one Document in Firestore to store latest update information and only listen to that 1 document. If there is a change, then update the local DB with the new data starting from the latest one in local DB

If anyone has a better answer please still leave comment here. Thank you community!

***** UPDATE:
There is a method to get the data only from cache:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(kCollection).get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
```

So just add the `GetOptions(source: Source.cache)` you can always fetch it from cache. Let me know if this could help.

== == == == == == ==

Comment: were you able to figure out any better solution than this. I am also facing a similar problem.

Comment: So I want to read the data periodically after some time. Would it be a good approach to make a Timestamp for each user to detect if I want to fetch new data or use cached data? Let's say that I want to update once a day so I check for difference between now and lastUpdated Timestamp and decide to use Source.Server or Source.Cache. Or would this be impossible since there can be only 30 minutes of inactivity?